# Why should I believe in the Siegel's and Hasse's rationale ? 

Tags: nt.number-theory, tate-shafarevich-groups, reference-request

Hello everyone,

I was deeply attracted by the Hasse and Siegel's theorems while studying $p$-adic analysis. While reading a paper *B.J. Birch and H.P.F. Swinnerton-Dyer - Notes on elliptic curves. I, Journ. reine u. angewandte Math. 212 (1963), 7-25* the authors emphasize that their central conjecture related to some cubic curves ( more popularly called as elliptic curves ) is based upon the work of Siegel and Tamagawa.

In that paper Peter points out that C.L. Siegel has done some work showing that "densities of rational points on a quadric surface can be expressed in terms of the densities of $p$ -adic points ". I was totally surprized that how can one get an intuition in what the author is pointing to.

More-over the Hasse-principle also tells the same thing. Existence of global solutions can be decided by looking at the local solutions. I can't understand the whole point. Suppose let us take a polynomial $f(x,y)=0$.

So my question is how can you estimate and find the solution set $(x,y)$ to $f$ seeing the solution set $(x^{\prime},y^{\ \prime})$ of $f(x,y)=0 \mod p$ .  So I am sure that $(x,y) \neq (x^{\prime},y^{\ \prime})$ in all cases. So are we merging all the obtained local $(x^{\prime},y^{\ \prime})$ solutions and thereby constructing $(x,y)$ ?.

Thank you.

Comment: Can anyone suggest me how to use $\Sha$ here. It doesn't turn beautifully. Generally in LaTeX we use some packages, but on the other hand I didn't get $\Sha$ working here. I just used Russian letter Sha for the mean time. All are welcome to edit my post replacing the Sha.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think we already met around here. 

Comment: Siegel's result is known as "mass formula" and is a corollary of the Siegel-Weil formula relating theta integral to Siegel-Eisenstein series. Roughly specking, the theta integral is connected with rational solutions while the Eisenstein series is connected with local solutions both $p$-adic and $\infty$-adic. Weil 's book "Adeles and algebraic groups" and two Acta papers 1964/65 is classic on this subject. 

Comment: @quid : Sorry, I cant understand what you are telling . Met around here ?.

Comment: Sha doesn't seem to work here, so using the unicode Ш is the best you can do.

Comment: @DavidRoberts :  Yes, Thank you !. But the problem is that even the Unicode Sha don't get changed in its appearance even after dressing with (Dollar). Generally alphabets appear differently if we dress them using (dollar symbol) for instance 'a' and '$a$'. But Sha seems to be the same all the places.  Ш and $ Ш$ are same ( Latter one is dressed with dollar )

Comment: What is the '1' that is appearing besides the post of quid ?. Is it some numbering given to some comments?

Comment: @unknown(google) : Yes , but the reference that Peter provided is "Uber Die Analytische Theorie Der Quadratischen Formen". I didn't find that link online. So do you say Tamagawa measure can be thought as a analogue of Seigel's work ? or something else.

Comment: Depends on browser - your second sha is serifed for me and the first is sans-serif. I'm using Chrome at present. the '1' means that someone has up-voted quid's comment. This requires a certain level of reputation to do.

Comment: That is the original paper of Siegel and hard to read. The referene I provided is more readable. Siegel's work could be translated using adele to the "Tamagawa measure one" staement.

Comment: @DavidRoberts : Thank you David, I never know that they are some voting flags. 

Comment: @quid : Oh, now it reads '6'. So 6 people believe that they have seen me earlier. But this is totally funny and weird experience. I created the account today after my friends suggestion. But I no way met you . Even your name is not real to meet you. I never know anyone by name 'quid'. I am a resident of Hyderabad. Its really funny to see that 6 people met me here . Let me know who are they, so that I can  wave my hands saying them "Hello" . I will also try to invite them to have a cup of cappuccino even.

Comment: Dear Shanmukha Srinivasan, by asking us to summarize the work of several authors, you are demanding too much of people who are working for free.  Please revise your question to be more specific, e.g., following the guidelines in the MathOverflow "how to ask" page, linked at the top of this page.

Comment: @S.Carnahan : Dear Carnahan, I noted your point. I try to present the lip-suctioned version of the question so that users can be comfortable in answering accordingly.

Comment: After not receiving any reply from quid, I thought of opening a meta-discussion ( after hearing that there is a MO META, where we can post such issues ) on his weird behavior. Anyone are free to join [there](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1397/a-strange-welcome-observed-is-it-spam-/) and comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that you shouldn't believe implicitly in it: like most local-global principles it is a heuristic until it is a theorem. Birch and S-Dyer used it that way.

Voskresenskii in his book *Algebraic Groups and Their Birational Invariants*, p. 138 of English translation, commented "One badly needs a monograph with a detailed exposition of all known results on Tamagawa numbers." If first written 20 years ago, that is probably true today still; especially if the scope is all algebraic groups, not just affine ones. (The whole point, really.)

See the Wikipedia articles on

*Glossary of arithmetic and Diophantine geometry

*Weil conjecture on Tamagawa numbers

*Smith–Minkowski–Siegel mass formula ‎ (recommended)

*Siegel–Weil formula

*Special values of L-functions

for decent coverage (by WP standards) bringing one up to the L-function theory in contemporary terms.

Comment: Its good to see that you work for Wikipedia. But your site don't hold an email id of you in case if I want to contact you.

Comment: I disagree with at least one of the above comments. 

Comment: I took my comment back, you can feel free to see my new lipo-suctioned edit. ;) 

Comment: But Charles, your answer is indeed nice. Only thing I wanted to hear is that I am interested in listening more about the Local-global principle, and why should one believe in it ?. I am particularly interested in knowing how can a local solution lifts to a global solution ?. @CharlesMatthews

Comment: So is everyone, however My personal view is based on my own research (actually I started with the Grothendieck–Katz p-curvature conjecture http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck-Katz_p-curvature_conjecture) which is that the local-global view encourages new research. You are reading mathematics written about 50 years ago, and asking a historians' question. Why not find your own problem? This worked for me, and Zariski-dense subgroups. Try works by Emmanuel Kowalski for a fresher approach.